# C# Composite key with Id in aggregate root pattern in ddd. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, aggregation

We are using ASP.NET MVC and EF 6.2.
We have an order and items and my colleague suggest this approach.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; } 
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column(Order = 0)]        
    public int Id { get; set; }    

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; 

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }    

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now we have a composite key (Id and OrderId) to enforce invariants. I don't understand that and I think we could have just composite key on OrderId (PK,FK) and ItemId(PK,FK) to achieve this. Could someone clear this for me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's almost correct.  The parent key should come first.  EG:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int OrderId { get; set; }

[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column(Order = 1)]        
public int Id { get; set; }
```

the point of this design is to store the OrderItem rows for each order together so they are cheaper to store and retrieve, and to minimize the number of indexes that are required for this table.  This design requires just a single clustered index, alternatives all require a separate index for the primary key and the foreign key.

Comment: But isn't the question whether the Id field is necessary at all?

Comment: Yes, the question basically if composite key of Id and OrderId gives any advantages over composite key of ItemId and OrderId.

Comment: I assumed multiple OrderItems on an Order could be the same Item.  So a “child table” not a many-to-many linking table.